# How to know when the last file is being visited in FileVisitor?

Tags: java, file-io, java-7, java.nio.file, nio2

I need to do something with the file visited last in a directory. How can I know if the current call to my `visitFile()` is the last one?

(I only want to list all the files and directories in a given directory. To do so, I've introduced a `depth` field to my `FileVisitor` implementation and in the `preVisitDirectory` I return `SKIP_SUBTREE` if the depth is greater than 0. (And then increment the `depth`.) The problem is that I don't know when to reset the `depth` to 0, because when I call the `walkFileTree` with this FileVisitor implementation for another directory, the `depth` is already > 0 and it only lists the given directory.)

Comment: "last file in a directory" as in name in ascending order? descending order? last modified? I don't think they are listed in any particular order...

Comment: True, it looks like the files are visited in name ascending order, I don't know how I could change that if I wanted. However, the order doesn't really matter. I would only like to know "when" is the last time the `visitFile()` is called (i.e. something like `if( !hasMoreFilesToVisit() )` ) regardless of the order of visiting.  (Or if there is a method invoked _just_ before `_walkFileTree_` returns that can be extended..)  In any case, you are right that "last file in a directory" is wrong. Editing it to "the file visited last in a directory".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about maintaining the depth only within the two methods, `preVisitDirectory` and `postVisitDirectory`? You'll increment `depth` in `preVisitDirectory` and decrement it in `postVisitDirectory`. You might have to initialize `depth` to `-1`, to have `depth == 0` when in the start directory though. That way, you'll always have the right `depth`.

Edit: If you return `SKIP_SIBLINGS` from `visitFile`, instead of from `preVisitDirectory`, the `postVisitDirectory` will still get called!

Here's a code sample:

```
public class Java7FileVisitorExample {

public void traverseFolder(Path start){
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

            private int depth = -1;

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                    throws IOException {
                System.out.println("preVisitDirectory(" + dir + ")");
                depth++;
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                    throws IOException {
                if (depth > 0) {
                    return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SIBLINGS;
                }

                System.out.println("visitFile(" + file + ", " + attrs + "): depth == " + depth);

                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException e)
                    throws IOException {
                if (e == null) {
                    depth--;
                    System.out.println("postVisitDirectory(" + dir + ")");
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                } else {
                    throw e;
                }


            }
        });
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().throwing(getClass().getName(), 
                "traverseFolder", ex);
    }
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Path start = Paths.get("/Book/Algorithm");
    new Java7FileVisitorExample().traverseFolder(start);
}
```

}

Comment: `postVisitDirectory` is only invoked for the given directory (when `depth==0`) since `preVisitDirectory` returns `SKIP_SUBTREE` which means that no other directories inside will be visited and thus `postVisitDirectory` methods will not be called for them. **But**, your answer made me realise the directories are "visited as files", i.e. in `visitFile` I can check if the file is a directory and decrement the `depth` if it is. So that solved my problem then, thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, you could return `SKIP_SIBLINGS` from `visitFile` whenever the `depth > 0` ...